# Login takes long time in Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, login

In my ubuntu 12.10 it takes lone time to login , i just upgraded this from 12.04 . I  suspect that it might be due to large number of folders in my `/home` . So please suggest me:

1. The way which help me to reduce login time
2. Also tell is it fine to put large no. of folders in /home Dir ? and
3. If not, how can i manage (and knows which folder is unnecessary) the folders in  /home Dir?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you install ***bootchart***. Search for it in the software center.
It will measure how much time each step of the boot takes and save a image file for you to analyse.

About the amount of folders in the home dir, I don't think it's the problem. I have lots in mine and my laptop boots in ~35 secs.

Aditionally, google for ***speed up my ubuntu*** os something like that. There are many tips and tutorials on that subject.

Comment: Thanks. I installed and checked that log. Please find the logs in attachment and let me suggest suitable solution .https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B5aVFocrjwU3UUZUYXlIWi1IYTg

Answer (score 1):

amount of folders in home directory is not an issue.

I am running a Core i7 CPU with 8 GB RAM and mine take from 95 seconds (minimum) to 125 seconds (maximum) just to bring up the GDM Login screen and then about ~25-35 seconds to show desktop after login. There are 11 directories inside my home directory and several applications that I enlisted to run at startup but none of them is heavy enough to affect the startup. I think this is an issue with the release as there are so many users complaining about the same. Previous setup of 12.04 on same machine used to bring up the desktop under ~20-30 seconds.

I also tried asking for help is IRC channel `#ubuntu` but nothing helped with the delay which occur after login to bring up the desktop. Looks like this is something to do with services which runs after login but I am all clueless. Hope someone can help us resolving the problem.

Comment: I recently installed Ubuntu 12.10 and I am also facing slow boot up. Though I have a rather archaic machine, but still the boot time is far too slow compared with that of Windows XP being booted from same machine. Just for the record, has your boot time improved after any possible upgrade?

Comment: @ShamimHafiz There have been a slight boost in boot up but it still takes ages to log in from LightDM screen to desktop. You can say, It takes 20% of total boot time from switching on the PC to get to the Login screen and then remaining 80% time from login to desktop.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved it:

1. installing dnsmask (local dns cache)
2. configured my eth0 from dhcp to static